# How do I get java scripts and their initiators (similar to Network tab) from Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I would like to list down the java scripts, css files and their initiator when open a URL using puppeteer.

I have looked into the trace option, but it does not show the initiator value.

Comment: see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1395

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Network.enable`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#method-enable) and [`Network.requestWillBeSent`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network#event-requestWillBeSent) from the Chrome DevTools Protocol to obtain the request URL and the initiator URL of a request:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

await client.send('Network.enable');

client.on('Network.requestWillBeSent', parameters => {
  const request_url = parameters.request.url;
  const initiator_url = parameters.initiator.url;

  console.log('The request', request_url, 'was initiated by', initiator_url, '.');
});
```